# Disable_with Ruby on rails don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

Disable_with Ruby on rails don't work

```
<%= f.submit "Sign In", class: "btn btn-success", data: {disable_with: " Signing in..."} %>
```

Comment: Is `jquery-rails` in your gem file?

Answer (score 1):

The `disable_with` option simply not working is probably because you're missing the unobtrusive javascript driver for Rails. The easiest/best way to get this is to include the [jquery-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) in your project.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

This contains the javascript that will notice the `data-disable-with` attribute on your submit button and make it change to the supplied value when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you, but jquery-rails is in my gemfile, not is it